# Create s3 event through Lambda script

Tags: events, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to trigger a Lambda function - "TriggerLambda", once a file named "File.csv" is put in a folder named "Files" that is present in an s3 bucket called "Processed".

```
bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification("Processed/Files")
response = bucket_notification.put(
        NotificationConfiguration={'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
            {
                'LambdaFunctionArn': Lambda_arn,
                'Events': [
                    's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                ],

            },
        ]})
```

This code is giving an error -

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid bucket name \"Processed/Files\": Bucket name must match the regex \"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{1,255}$\"",
```

Comment: The error is saying that there is no bucket named `Processed/Files`. You say that your bucket name is `Processed`, so change your code to match. The [`put_bucket_notification_configuration()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_notification_configuration) shows a **Filter** that can accept a **prefix**.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Here, they are asking for Topic and Queue ARN. This is not needed when we create events through UI. Can you explain a bit on that?

Comment: Amazon S3 bucket notifications can trigger an AWS Lambda function _or_ send a message to an Amazon SNS queue. Try leaving out the `QueueConfigurations` section.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So, only Lambda configuration will do? Or SNS is also required?

Comment: Just pick one! You don't need both.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It says "event is not supported for notifications."

Comment: Please update your Question to show your code.